# How can I draw a line graph using values in a file?

Tags: java, android, file

I'm making an android app that tells you the difference of your sizes compared to the ideal sizes. I want to add a function that keep track of the input size and show it with a line graph. Some details:

1. I try to use 'achartengine' as a library.
2. Whenever the user input his weight(in double), it should be added in a file.
3. By reading the values of weight in a file, it should draw a line graph.

How can I save the values in a file repeatedly as an array list of double? Then, how can I use that values to draw a line graph?

Answer (score 1):

I would just you to use `AchartEngine` to draw graphs.. See this [link](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html).You will find the demo there

Comment: I tried to use AchartEngine, but I don't know how to save the input values in a file and bring it in a form of an arraylist of double.

Comment: Why dont you add input values to Arraylist of type double

Comment: Does the txt file recognize the arraylist of type double?